# How to properly send context, activity and interface connection in method ?

Tags: java, android

I have this method :

```
    public LeftDrawerView(Activity activity, Context context, LeftDrawerViewInterface delegate)
{
   this.activity = activity;
   this.context = context;
   this.delegate = delegate;
}
```

To call above method, I call with below method :

```
LeftDrawerView leftDrawerView new LeftDrawerView(this, this, this);
```

Which might confuse later on, I wan to simplify this, is there any way to do this ?

I could call individual variables like this :

```
LeftDrawerView leftDrawerView new LeftDrawerView();
leftDrawerView.context = this;
leftDrawerView.activity = this;
leftDrawerView.delegate = this;
```

This more readable, but more code to do. want to avoid this. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one more constructor which will call your existing one:

```
public LeftDrawerView(Activity from) {
  this(from, from, from);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just pass your CustomActivity like this:

```
public LeftDrawerView(CustomActivity customActivity){
   this.customActivity = customActivity;
}
```

And than, if you need, to just cast this way:

```
((Activity) LeftDrawerView.this.customActivity);
((Context) LeftDrawerView.this.customActivity);
((LeftDrawerViewInterface) LeftDrawerView.this.customActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this:

```
public LeftDrawerView () {};
```

Then you would create the appropriate setters:

```
public void setActivity(Activity activity) {...};
```

And finally the appropriate getters:

```
public Activity getActivity() {...};

public Context getContext() {...};

public LeftDrawerViewInterface getLeftDrawerViewInterface() {...};
```

You would use a single attribute to store the `Activity` instance and then, on each getter, you would do the right cast.